# gcp create metric health checks from health check logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to create a metric on health check for a backend service (load balancer). I need this metric to trigger alerts on failed health checks.

From: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/kinds-and-types

> Emulating string-valued custom metrics
>
> String values in custom metrics are not supported, but you can
> replicate string-valued metric functionality in the following ways:
>
> - Create a GAUGE metric using an INT64 value as an enum that
>   maps to a string value. Externally translate the enum to a string
>   value when you query the metric.
> - Create a GAUGE metric with a BOOL value and a label whose
>   value is one of the strings you want to monitor. Use the boolean to
>   indicate if the value is the active value.

For example, suppose you want to create a string-valued metric called "status" with possible options OK, OFFLINE, or PENDING. You could make a GAUGE metric with a label called status_value. Each update would write three time series, one for each status_value (OK, OFFLINE, or PENDING), with a value of 1 for "true" or 0 for "false".

Using Terraform, I tried this, but not sure if it's really converting the values "UNHEALTHY" and "HEALTHY" to 0/1s.  I tried to switch metric_type to GAUGE instead of DELTA, but the error from Terraform said I needed to use DELTA, and DISTRIBUTION is required for the value_type. Has anybody tried the docs above where it says GAUGE metric with BOOL value?  Don't we need some kind of map of strings to boolean?

Here is my terraform:

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric" {
  name   = var.name
  filter = "logName=projects/[project_id]/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fhealthchecks"
  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = "DELTA"
    value_type  = "DISTRIBUTION"
    labels {
      key         = "status"
      value_type  = "STRING"
      description = "status of health check"
    }
    display_name = var.display_name
  }
  value_extractor = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.request)"
  label_extractors = {
    "status" = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.healthState)"
  }
  bucket_options {
    linear_buckets {
      num_finite_buckets = 3
      width              = 1
      offset             = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share any error messages ?

Comment: There is no real error outside of having the right configuration.  Maybe it's better phrased, how to configure gauge and boolean off of the gcp health check log name: projects/[project_id]/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fhealthcheck